# Database and Table Management

Tags: php, sql, database

I have been creating a web app and am looking to expand. In my web app I have a table for users which includes privileges in order to track whether a user is an administrator, a very small table for a dynamic content section of a page, and a table for tracking "events" on the website.

Being not very experienced with web application creation, I'm not really sure about how professionals would create systems of databases and tables for a web application. In my web app, I plan to add further user settings for each member of the website and even a messaging system. I currently use PHP with a MySQL database that I query for all of my commands, but I would be willing to change any of this if necessary. What would be the best wat to track content such as messages that are interpersonal and also specific user settings for each user. Would I want to have multiple databases at any point? Would I want to have multiple tables for each user, perhaps? Any information on how this is done or should be done would be quite helpful.

I'm sorry about the broadness of the question, but I've been wanting to reform this web app since I feel that my ideas for table usage are not on par with those that experienced programmers have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my seemingly long, hopefully not too convoluted answer to your question. I think I've covered most, if not all of your queries.

For your web app, you could have a table of users called "Users", settings table called "UserSettings" or something equally as descriptive, and messages in "PrivateMessages" table. Then there could be child tables that store extra data that is required.

User security can be a tricky thing to design and implement. Do you want to do it by groups (if you plan on having many users, making it easier to manage their permissions), or just assign individually due to a small user base? For security alone, you'd end up with 4 tables:

```
Users
UserSettings
UserGroups
UserAssignedGroups
```

That way you can have user info, settings, groups they can be assigned to and what they ARE assigned to separated properly. This gives you a decent amount of flexibility and conforms to normalization standards (as mentioned above by DrSAR).

With your messages, don't store them with the username, but rather the User ID. For instance, in your PrivateMessages table, you would have a MessageID, SenderUserID, RecipientUserID, Subject, Body and DateSent to store the most basic info. That way, when a user wants to check their received messages, you can query the table saying:

```
   SELECT * FROM PrivateMessages WHERE RecipientUserID = 123556
```

A list of tables for your messages could be as such:

```
PrivateMessages
MessageReplies
```

The PrivateMessages table can store the parent message, and then the MessageReplies table can store the subsequent replies. You could store it all in one table, but depending on traffic and possibly writing recursive functions to retrieve all messages and replies from one table, a two table approach would be simplest I feel.

If I were you, I'd sit down with a pencil and paper, and write down/draw what I want to track in my database. That way you can then draw links between what you want to store, and see how it will come together. It helps me when I'm trying to visualise things.

Comment: So many great answers. This is amazing. This is exactly the kind of thing I'm interested in doing. I'd rep you all the way if I could.

Answer (score 0):

For the scope of your web app you don't need multiple databases. You do need, however, multiple tables to store your data efficiently.

For user settings, always use a separate table. You want your "main" users table as lean as possible, since it will be accessed (= searched) every time a user will try to log in. Store IDs, username, password (hashed, of course) and any other field that you need to access when authenticating. Put all the extra information in a separate table. That way your login will only query a smaller table and once the user is authenticated you can use its ID to get all other information from the secondary table(s).

Messages can be trickier because they're a bigger order of magnitude - you might have tens or hundreds for each user. You need to design you table structure based on your application's logic. A table for each user is clearly not a feasible solution, so go for a general messages table but implement procedures to keep it to a manageable size. An example would be "archiving" messages older than X days, which would move them to another table (which works well if your users aren't likely to access their old messages too often). But like I said, it depends on your application.

Good luck!

Comment: Two questions (thanks for the great answer, by the way):
What would I make separate settings tables be identified with? User ID or username?
Also, for querying the messages if all are stored inside of one table, what do you think would be a good way of going about choosing messages to display according to the user? Something like SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username = '$username' type of business.

Again, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Always use IDs instead of usernames, the search is much faster. So you'd have the main users table have the fields id, username, password (I cannot stress enough how important is for this one to be properly hashed) + any other fields that are required for login. Then you'd (probably) have a user information table with user_id (which is the id from users) and user information fields. Same for user settings. Messages are similar, just remember that you will need columns for sender and receiver (both pointing to IDs in the users table).

Comment: Don't worry about password hashing. I've implemented that since the beginning of the web app with md5(). This is only something to be done with the password in this table, right? That's funny you mention the sender/reciever columns -- I was just planning implementation of that in that manner. _Really_, thanks for the help in this. I couldn't do it without helpful people like you.

Comment: If you want to be thorough, md5() is not enough. You should also use salt - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164107.aspx and http://skfox.com/2007/12/18/md5-hashes-and-salt/.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Cristian Radu's comments: you need to split your data into different tables. The lean user table will (in fact, should) have one unique ID per user. This (unique) key should be repeated in the secondary tables. It will then be called a foreign key. Obviously, you want a key that's unique. If your username can be guaranteed to be unique (i.e. you require user be identified by their email address), then you can use that. If user names are real names (e.g. Firstname Sirname), then you don't have that guarantee and you need to keep a userid which becomes your key. Similarly, the table containing your posts could (but doesn't have to) have a field with unique userids indicating who wrote it etc.

You might want to read a bit about database design and the concept of normalization: (http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) No need to get bogged down with the n-th form of normalization but it will help you at this stage where you need to figure out the database design.

Good luck and report back ;-)

Comment: This is just great. I really really wish I could rep you guys. (No privileges yet, though, since I'm rather new to this forum) In my case, I have usernames that are unique, and I actually have a currently unused auto-incrementing ID number for users. In the case of the foreign key you spoke of, would it be preferable to use the auto-incrementing integer ID or the more complex username?

Comment: Auto-incrementing IDs are fine for keys - this has the advantage of guaranteeing uniqueness. However, it is usually recommended to avoid redundant information in your tables (this is one of the requirements to be met when normalizing a database) which you have due to essentially there being two IDs per table entry. In your case, I would not worry too much - your database server is not going to care either way and performance or data volume won't be a consideration.